# Adding new column and set GETDATE as value in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my query:

```
alter table reseau add datemodification datetime default getdate()
```

After execution the rows have `NULL` as their value but I want them set to the current value of `GETDATE()`.

How can do I do this?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2008, you should **really** stop using `Datetime` and `getdate()` , and use `datetime2(n)` and `sysdatetime()` instead ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DEFAULT` is a `CONSTRAINT` that sets the value of a column when you omit it when performing an `INSERT`. If you want to then want to create a column with a `DEFAULT` value, and populate it at the point it with said `DEFAULT` value at the point of creating it then add `WITH VALUES` at the end of the statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.test (ID int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Test ADD D datetime DEFAULT GETDATE() WITH VALUES;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Test;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Test;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=07a32592c484b43e89cab6235f56be39)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update existing values after adding the column, then use `update`:

```
update reseau
    set datemodification = getdate();
```

The default takes effect for *new* rows.

Alternatively, you can define the column to be `not null`:

```
alter table reseau add datemodification not null datetime default getdate();
```

Then the existing rows will use the `default` value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a06115afe3aaa61e7dc03e03d49b555) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating the two methods.

Comment: @ZakariaBadis . . . You *do* add a new column.  It depends if you want it to be NULL-able.  If you do, then you need to use `update`.  If not, then the default value is used.